# Передача в функцию функции с именованными переменными

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача состоит в том чтобы передать в функцию в качестве аргумента другую функцию с указанием конкретных значений именованных переменных.

На примере:

```
def summ(a, b, k = 1):
    return (a + b) * k

def subtract(a, b, k = 1):
    return (a - b) * k

def calculate(function, a, b):
    y = function(a, b)
    print('The result of the function is', y)
    return a + b

n1 = 4
n2 = 7
calculate(summ(n1, n2, k = 2), n1, n2)
```

В текущем виде код не работает, выдает ошибку "'int' object is not callable", по видимому проблема в том что внутри функции calculate происходит попытка запихнуть аргументы a и b в функцию для которой они уже определены (даже если значения изначально у них одинаковы).

Если вызывать функцию таким образом:

```
calculate(summ, n1, n2)
```

то все работает. Но нужна именно возможность уже на этом этапе задавать конкретное значение параметра k.

Возможно ли это как то сделать?  Без использования глобальных переменных и без передачи k отдельным аргументом функции calculate.

Я начинающий пользователь Python, и подозреваю что упускаю какое то очевидное решение, но самому его найти мне не удалось.

Comment: `calculate(functools.partial(summ, k=2), n1, n2)`

Answer (score 4):

```
from functools import partial
calculate(partical(summ, some arguments), n1, n2))
```

Заместо `some arguments` через запятую пишите сначала неименованные аргументы сколько вам нужно, а потом именованные, функция partical по сути заполняет часть аргументов как аргументы по умолчанию, и дает доопределить

1. **Пример:**

   ````py
   from functools import partical
   def plus(a,b):
       return a + b
   new_plus = partical(plus, 5) # эквивалентно функции plus с одним аргументом b и вторым аргументом по умолчанию a = 5.
   print(plus(5)) # 10
   print(plus(4)) # 9 ```
   ````

Answer (score 4):

Можно например сделать так:

```py
def calculate(function, a, b, **kwargs):
    y = function(a, b, **kwargs)
    print('The result of the function is', y)
    return a + b


n1 = 4
n2 = 7
calculate(summ, n1, n2, k=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильно подозреваете. Вам нужно смотреть на [`partial` фунцию](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Вот примерно что она делает:

```py
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```